# Fixed Background Image resizing

Tags: html, css

I have 2 sections, with 2 background images covering the whole width and height of those sections, and both are "fixed" position.
Everything works fine, until I tryed out to zoom out to see page. The background image of the second section "biosecond" just cut in half. I have it set to fixed. Anyone know a solution? Maybe a bigger image? Once again, the problem is when you zoom out the page few times.

Here is it on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ryufd7sq/2/)  zoom out on browser to see the messed up image
Here is the Html, css is to long, so don't want to mess up:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="bio">
    <section>
        <div class="centerMid" id="sndColmn">
            <img src="images/profilepic.jpg" alt="Amir Cisija" width="300" height="300">
            <div id="bscInfo">
                    <h4>Name </h4>


                    <h4>Born </h4>


                    <h4>Current residence </h4>


            </div>
        </div>
            <h1><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</strong></h1>

        <br />
        <p>Aliquam semper egestas orci <span class="span">Amir Cisija</span> rhoncus <span>"aortaFX"</span> pharetra ut. Nullam aliquet orci non lacus pellentesque commodo. Donec id leo ut ante pretium hendrerit id et arcu. Nam ut nisi orci. Integer venenatis finibus vulputate. Duis porttitor vel nunc eu iaculis. Mauris consectetur sit amet lectus id cursus.</p>
        <br />
            <h2><strong>Pellentesque habitant</strong></h2>

        <br />
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque tempor est et lectus ornare molestie. Duis tincidunt lobortis ex vitae tincidunt. Ut posuere tortor vitae nisi elementum, non molestie erat pharetra. Donec eget placerat ante. Nulla vitae nunc id neque gravida lobortis. Morbi quam velit, volutpat non eros sit amet, tristique vehicula ipsum.</p>
        <br />
        <p>Integer finibus nunc nibh, id aliquam sem sollicitudin ac. In at elit a risus pellentesque posuere quis quis ipsum. Vestibulum at ante a turpis egestas pellentesque accumsan quis arcu. Nam suscipit ac nulla pretium rutrum. Maecenas semper dictum arcu quis ullamcorper.</p>
        <br />
        <p>Vestibulum tempor commodo ipsum. Integer consectetur purus est, quis congue diam tincidunt sit amet. Integer id mi vel ipsum dapibus semper. Integer ultricies ut enim ac faucibus. Ut ac magna non magna porta sodales. Nulla venenatis orci a turpis egestas, ut rutrum arcu consectetur.</p>
        <br>
    </section>
</div>
<div id="biosecond" class="biosecond">
    <br />
    <div class="secondSec">
            <h2>Key Qualifications:</h2>

        <br />
        <ul>
            <li>xxxxxxxx</li>
            <li>xxxxxxxx</li>
            <li>xxxxxxxx</li>
            <li>xxxxxxxx</li>
            <li>xxxxxxxx</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="secondSec">
            <h2>Secondary Qualifications:</h2>

        <br />
        <ul>
            <li>xxxxxxxx</li>
            <li>xxxxxxx</li>
            <li>xxxxxx</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="secondSec">
            <h2>Activities:</h2>

        <br />
        <ul>
            <li>xxxxxxxx</li>
            <li>xxxxxxxx</li>
            <li>xxxxxxxx</li>
            <li>xxxxxxxx</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfooter"></div>
<div class="footer" id="footer"></div>enter code here
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like `background-size: cover` ?

Comment: @drip it's doing the job, but it scales up. I guess I leave it if I can't get it to keep proportion like the normal. Thank you.